# Why the sum$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(n^{n^a}-1\right)$ converges when a is strictly less then -1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(n^{n^a}-1\right)$$

Plugging in numbers on wolfram alpha I know that this sum converges when a is strictly less than -1. It is kinda very similar to the p-series test because we literally have a p-series 1/n^p in the power of n when p=-a and a<0. But I need to know WHY the sum converges WHEN a<-1. I can prove all the situations when the sum Diverges when a is greater or equal to -1 except this one. [Picture of the sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w1Vy.jpg)

Comment: Note that for $a\lt0$$$n^{n^a}-1\sim\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n^{-a}}$$and $\sum\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n^{-a}}$ converges for $a\lt-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Peter! I am just learning right now, so could you please explain why they have a similar rate?

Comment: I know that we can write it like this: e^(n^(ln(n)/n^(-a))-1

Comment: Can we use comparison test to prove this or is ther any other proof of such relation?

Comment: @PeterForeman could you please show me?

Comment: Because $e^x-1\sim x$ as $x\to0$ and so$$n^{n^a}-1=e^{\ln{(n)}/n^{-a}}-1\sim\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n^{-a}}$$as $\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n^{-a}}\to0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just such a click moment in my brain right now haha! After so many hours of thinking it ends up so easy